# prototype: loop with each and select childs by classname

Tags: prototypejs

I have following structure:

html structure:

```
<table class="structure">
<tr>
    <td class="id"> 
        <div class="product-id">123</div>
    </td>
    <td class="article">
        <ul name="attribute[151]">
            <li class="active"> <a href="..." rel="1">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="..." rel="2">B</a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="id"> 
        <div class="product-id">456</div>
    </td>
    <td class="article">
        <ul name="attribute[151]">
            <li class="active"> <a href="..." rel="1">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="..." rel="2">B</a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to loop every tr element to get the li element with class active. I pick tr because i also want to select the product-id.
how can i select a css selector inside my each loop?

prototype:

```
 $$('.structure tr').each(
            function (index) {
                    //wrong
               console.log(index.down(".article li.active a'").readAttribute('rel'));
            }
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can simplify your javascript like this

```
$$('.structure tr').each(
        function (index) {

           console.log(index.down('li.active a').readAttribute('rel'));

                //wrong
           console.log(index.down(".article li.active a'").readAttribute('rel'));
                //       extra single quote           ^^^^
        }
    );

}
```

You also have an extra single quote (') in the `down()` method which might be confusing the CSS selector engine (which is Sizzle)